# Why is everyone inside one room - Terraria iPad

Tags: terraria-mobile

I started up Terraria on my iPad and I saw all my NPCs were in my friend's room.

Help Me What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

They probably just walked around. At night they will go back into their rooms.